# CSS animation of elements popping over other elements on Hover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a menu that looks a bit like theses "apps panel" we can sometimes see.

So I have 6 elements, side-by-side without any space between them, and when I hover one of them it slightly pops, as you can see here :

```css
#account-bubble .account-param {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 position: absolute;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 border: 1px solid #CCC;
 background: #F7F7F7;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
 transition-duration: 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition-property: transform;
 transition-property: transform;
 z-index: 0;
}
#account-bubble .account-param:hover, #account-bubble .account-param:focus, #account-bubble .account-param:active {
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
 transform: scale(1.2);
 z-index: 5000;
}

.p1 {
 top: 15px;
 left: 15px;
}

.p2 {
 top: 15px;
 left: 74px;
}

.p3 {
 top: 15px;
 left: 133px;
}

.p4 {
 top: 74px;
 left: 15px;
}

.p5 {
 top: 74px;
 left: 74px;
}

.p6 {
 top: 74px;
 left: 133px;
}

#account-bubble .profil-picture img {

}

#account-bubble .account-param {
 
}
```

```html
<div id="account-bubble">
   <div class="account-param p1">
   </div>
   <div class="account-param p2">
   </div>
   <div class="account-param p3">
   </div>
   <div class="account-param p4">
   </div>
   <div class="account-param p5">
   </div>
   <div class="account-param p6">
   </div>
  </div>
```

To do this I had to set my elements's position to `absolute` and then position each of them 1px over their element-neighbour in order to avoid having a 2px border. (it was not possible to use a table with border-collapse due to the transform css that makes the element pops - It would pop without the border.)

My problem is that when I hover an element, my code does what I expect, but when i leave my cursor the element immediatly reset its z-index to its initial value, making the "unhover animation" very ugly.

Does anyone have any idea/suggestion on how I can realize this trick ? Or a better alternative to my code ? (I would prefere to stick with CSS for this)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to decrease `z-index` slowly, you can use `transition` for that.

```
-webkit-transition-property: transform, z-index;
transition-property: transform, z-index;
```

---

If you want to use different hover on / hover off options, you can.

```
#element {
    /* HOVER OFF */
    -webkit-transition-property: transform, z-index;
    transition-property: transform, z-index;
}

#element:hover {
    /* HOVER ON */
    -webkit-transition-property: transform;
    transition-property: transform;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this works better than what I did, thank you. However the animation is still a little bit sloppy, do you know if there is a way to have the transition effect only I hover out but not when I hover in ? Does CSS allows that ?

Comment: @apatik Yes, it's possible. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks !! Now with this I can adjust the numbers to get a perfect slide.

Answer (score 1):

The z-index is animatable so make sure to include it in your transitions by using `transition-property: all;`

```css
#account-bubble .account-param {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 position: absolute;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 border: 1px solid #CCC;
 background: #F7F7F7;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
 transition-duration: 0.3s;
    /* change the transition-property to all */
 -webkit-transition-property: all;
 transition-property: all;
 z-index: 0;
}
#account-bubble .account-param:hover, #account-bubble .account-param:focus, #account-bubble .account-param:active {
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
 transform: scale(1.2);
 z-index: 5000;
}

.p1 {
 top: 15px;
 left: 15px;
}

.p2 {
 top: 15px;
 left: 74px;
}

.p3 {
 top: 15px;
 left: 133px;
}

.p4 {
 top: 74px;
 left: 15px;
}

.p5 {
 top: 74px;
 left: 74px;
}

.p6 {
 top: 74px;
 left: 133px;
}

#account-bubble .profil-picture img {

}

#account-bubble .account-param {
 
}
```

```html
<div id="account-bubble">
   <div class="account-param p1">
   </div>
   <div class="account-param p2">
   </div>
   <div class="account-param p3">
   </div>
   <div class="account-param p4">
   </div>
   <div class="account-param p5">
   </div>
   <div class="account-param p6">
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your solutions looks similar to Genhis's one and it works fine ! However as you can see the animation is still a little bit sloppy and I was wondering if CSS allows to have a transition effect only when I hover-out but not when I hover-in ? Can CSS differenciate this ? Anyways thanks for the help !